# My sidebar Floating at bottom

Tags: html, css

In my custom template file, which i made for youtube videos-creating problem with my sidebar, it is showing the sidebar at bottom, below is the code i am using..

Can anyone help me, it should stick at right, as it..

```
<?php
/**

 Template Name: gallery

*/


get_header(); 
?>
<style>
/* some basic styling */

h1 {font-size:20px; line-height:95%;}

#galvidcontainer {
  width:1100px;
  margin-left:50px;
  height:1250px;
}

.galvidpre {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  background-color:#00A0DA;
}

.galvidprevid {
  width:300px;
}

.galvidpretext {
  width:280px;
  padding-top:2px;
  margin-top:2px;
}

</style>

<div id="galvidcontainer">
<h1>Videos</h1>

     <?php /* Loop the stuff from the videos post type */
          $args = array( 'post_type' => 'videos', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
          <div class="galvidpre">
               <div class="galvidprevid">
               <?php
               /* Set variables and create if stament */
                $videosite = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Video Site', single);
                $videoid = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Video ID", single);
                if ($videosite == vimeo) {  
                echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$videoid.'" width="300" height="190" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
                } else if ($videosite == youtube) {
                echo '<iframe width="300" height="190" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videoid.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                } else {
                echo 'Please Select Video Site Via the CMS';
                }
                ?>
               </div>
               <div class="galvidpretext">
                    <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
                    <p>
                    <?php /* this is just a limit on characters displayed */
                    $words = explode(" ",strip_tags(get_the_content()));
                    $content = implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,20));
                    echo $content; ?>
                    </p>
               </div>

</div>

     <?php endwhile;?>

</div>
<?php get_sidebar() ?> 
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

The thing happening with the sidebar>>https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeWXy.png

Comment: Add `border: 1px solid #f00;`  to your containers and see what is happening. Most likely, they just can't fit on the page.

Comment: Try to decrease your sidebar width or show us a live example where we can look

Comment: After the changes you said, >>http://i.imgur.com/l2thcTl.png

Comment: Jashwant i also decreased the width of the main container and space available for sidebar, but it is not coming up

Comment: Where is the CSS for the sidebar?

Comment: Dannis i m just calling the sidebar by>><?php get_sidebar() ?> ,, not using any css for that

Comment: You must style the `sidebar` and you must put the `sidebar` inside the main wrapper and of course `float` content and sidebar side by side giving them both `float: left;` property or `content { float: left; }` `sidebar { float: right; }` and fix the widths for both like `content { width: 70% }` `sidebar { width: 30% }` of course you must count the borders too.

Comment: mdesdev, i have implemented but footer also came up, the code i changed:

Comment: `#galvidcontainer {
  width:70%;
  margin-left:50px;
  height:1250px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  float:left;
  clear:right;
}
galvidcontainer.clear { 
    clear:both; 
}
.galvidpre {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  background-color:#00A0DA;
}

.galvidprevid {
  width:300px;
}

.galvidpretext {
  width:280px;
  padding-top:2px;
  margin-top:2px;
}
.sidebar {
float:right;
width:30%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to clear the floats. Use [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) or clear:both

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix"></div>


.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Avoid **Link-Only** answers. These answers will become **invalid once the link is broken**. Include relevant code snippets here and use link for reference.

Comment: Hey chris, can you please implement that and tell me the code then, i did but failed

Comment: try give the "galvidcontainer" the claerfix class and add the clearfix css to your css file